# Scrape Highchart, missing data

Tags: web-scraping, highcharts, google-chrome-console, web-console

I've been trying to scrape a specific highchart, using console commands, something in the line off:

`data = $('div#graphCont2').highcharts().series[0].data; { console.log(data)}`

This code works on the following site, I retrieve all data.
[test-hichart1](https://www.crisil.com/en/home/what-we-do/financial-products/indices.html)

However, when I rework the code for the graph I intend to scrape ([chart](https://www.energiemarktinformatie.nl/beurzen/elektra/), Its the uppermost chart, APX-PSE for all X and Y entries), I miss data. It varies somehow (based on the timestamps, it seems to vary by the selected period), but I only get data from around timestamp 1562284800000 and onwards when the period is set to "all" (thus missing 2/3 of all entries).

I use this code:

```
data = $('div#stockchart_apx').highcharts().series[0].data; { console.log(data) }
```

My idea was to use a `console.table` to get the info I need, though I'm unsure if the table is usable past 999 entries anyway.
Does anyone have an idea of why the readout fluctuates and how I can retrieve all the information?

Thanks!

EDIT~ so, after a couple more hours, I managed to get all data by opening the graph in full-window mode. I'm unsure to where the differences originate from, but it worked. I scraped the data with:

```
data = $('div#stockchart_apx').highcharts().series[0].data;
const getCircularReplacer1 = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
};

JSON.stringify(data, getCircularReplacer1());
```

Comment: Try this one: `Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data`

Comment: It works equally great! See:

```data = Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data;
const getCircularReplacer2 = () => {
  const seen = new WeakSet();
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (seen.has(value)) {
        return;
      }
      seen.add(value);
    }
    return value;
  };
};

JSON.stringify(data, getCircularReplacer2());```

However, the problems with the missing data seem to originate from the selected periods (1m, 3m, 6m, 1y, all). When I select "all", I still only get 6m or 1y (except for a single try).